# RxJs - Convert Flickr request to stream of photos

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm a RXJS newbie. 
Trying to figure out why this code doesn't work.

```
var $sources = $('#clickme');

var flickrApi = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=af11a8fa73ca2894e2f7c46ecd7a5a87&text=puppies&per_page=5&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";

Rx.Observable.fromEvent($sources, 'click')
.flatMap(click => Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON(flickrApi)))
.flatMap(response => Rx.Observable.fromArray(response.photos))
.subscribe(photo => console.log("The photo Object", photo));
```

The object is to run this flickr api, receive the photos and create a stream of single photo events.
For some reason `subscribe` doesn't happen.

Live (non-working) demo here: http://jsbin.com/pesiqo/2/edit

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not valid JavaScript (JavaScript does not have lambdas).

You should also supply an error handler to your `subscribe` call to catch any runtime errors that occur.  And you should check the response from Flickr to see if the request succeeded.

Just changing your code to valid JavaScript and it runs just fine, though it fails due to an invalid flickr API key.

```
var $sources = $('#clickme');

var flickrApi = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=af11a8fa73ca2894e2f7c46ecd7a5a87&text=puppies&per_page=5&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";

Rx.Observable.fromEvent($sources, 'click')
.flatMap(function (click) {
  return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON(flickrApi));
})
.flatMap(function (response) {
  if (response.stat === "fail") {
    return Rx.Observable.throw(new Error(response.message));
  }
  return Rx.Observable.fromArray(response.photos);
})
.subscribe(function (photo) {
  console.log("The photo Object", photo);
}, function (error) {
  console.log("an error occurred", error, error.message, error.stack);
});
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/tupowacila/3/edit

Comment: Thanks - Although - My code IS javascript ES6 valid code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Sure but ES6 is not broadly supported yet. For example, it did not work in my Chrome 40 beta.

Comment: Ok. I should mention that you need to enable "experimental javascript" in about:flags for it to work.